# Change pin color in javascript map?

Tags: javascript, html, json, amcharts

We're using an amcharts map, and so far, it all looks pretty good.

What I'm trying to do is change the color of the pins based on *some* value coming from our `json` stream.

`javascript`:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
"type": "map",
"theme": "light",
"imagesSettings": {
  "rollOverColor": "#089282",
  "rollOverScale": 1,
  "selectedScale": 0.5,
  "selectedColor": "#089282",
  "color": "#13564e",
  "selectable": false,
  "bringForwardOnHover": false
},
"areasSettings": {
  "color": "#D3D3D3",
"autoZoom": true
},  
"data": {
  "map": "puertoRicoHigh",
  "getAreasFromMap": true
},
"dataLoader": {
  "url": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/716619/30189.json",
  "format": "json",
  "showErrors": true,
  "postProcess": function(data, config, map) {
    // create a new dataProvider
    var mapData = map.data;

    // init images array
    if (mapData.images === undefined)
      mapData.images = [];

    // create images out of loaded data
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var image = data[i];
      image.type = "circle";
      mapData.images.push(image);
    }
    return mapData;
  }
}
```

});

That works well, but I would like to change the pins being displayed in the map. Ideally, I would like to use images (jpg, png, etc) that I've downloaded from the web.

So let's say that my `json` looks like this:

```
[{"title":"Site1","longitude":18.4262,"latitude":-67.1483,"inservice":true},
{"title":"Site2","longitude":18.3663,"latitude":-66.1887,"inservice":false}]
```

How can I change the pin color/size/font (or even image) so that if "inservice" is true, then use one pin. If it's false, then use another pin.

I tried using the SO snippet tool, but it's not rendering the map. So here it is, in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wn61bfqb/

```js
 AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "theme": "light",
  "imagesSettings": {
    "rollOverColor": "#089282",
    "rollOverScale": 1,
    "selectedScale": 0.5,
    "selectedColor": "#089282",
    "color": "#13564e",
    "selectable": false,
    "bringForwardOnHover": false
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "color": "#D3D3D3",
 "autoZoom": true
  },  
  "data": {
    "map": "puertoRicoHigh",
    "getAreasFromMap": true
  },
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/716619/30189.json",
    "format": "json",
    "showErrors": true,
    "postProcess": function(data, config, map) {
      // create a new dataProvider
      var mapData = map.data;
      
      // init images array
      if (mapData.images === undefined)
        mapData.images = [];
      
      // create images out of loaded data
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var image = data[i];
        image.type = "circle";
        mapData.images.push(image);
      }
      return mapData;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#mapdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/puertoRicoHigh.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.js"></script>
<div id="mapdiv"></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside the dataLoader function where your are looping through the datasets add a check if `inservice` is true. Based on this check add a color.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var image = data[i];
    image.type = "circle";
  if(data[i].inservice){
     image.color = 'green'; // if inservice is true
  } else {
     image.color = 'red'; // if inservice is false or undefined 
  }
    mapData.images.push(image);
  }
```

I noticed that the end point you are calling to create this map is not returning `inservice` field yet. So till then we end up showing red pin all the time.

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/wn61bfqb/8/)